# What is the hook to alter links in the Book Outline tree?

Tags: navigation, nodes

What is the theme hook to alter links in the book outline like theme_menu_link__menu does for menus?  Or is there a way to make theme_menu_link__menu apply changes to a tree view of the Books?  Not the book navigation but the Outline.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there isn't one.  Had to go back to an ajax approach and update the book outline in the client browser.